# tc qdisc not delete filter

Tags: tc

I have a problem with understand tc behaviour, especially how is working qdisc deletion.
My main problem is why tc qdisc did not delete the attached filter?
I did:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth ingress
tc qdisc add dev eth parent ffff....
tc filter add dev eth protocol ip....
tc qdisc del dev eth root
```

Last command should have deleted qdisc with its attached filter, but when I did

```
tc filter show dev eth
```

the filter was still existing.
Have I done something wrong or can I delete the filter only by command `tc filter del...`?

Answer (score 1):

the *ingress* handle is reserved (with value *ffff:*) and separate from the *root* handle, so it has to be deleted separately (likewise, it was added separately from the root handle). To delete it (and as a consequence all filters below it), simply issue this command:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth ingress
```